# 2D array with discrete colors not working for one middle value

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a 2D array of values between 0 and (including) 22.
I want every value to have a discrete colour and hover value assigned to it in a normal matshow plot.
I tried it with just a Colormap and with a normalization but the colours 15 and 16 are not consistent.

Without any normalization 15 has the colour of 16 (and of course the hover values are misaligned floats).
With normalization, everything is fine except 16 has the colour of 15.

I saw multiple other questions asking the same thing but following the answers resulted in this problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

example_data = [list(range(23))]*4
cmaplist = [
    "#b3b3b3", "#333333", "#8a745c", "#8f7456",
    "#847362", "#1a53ff", "#336600", "#aa8a31",
    "#b3b3b3", "#aa8a31", "#aa8a31", "#004d00",
    "#aa8a31", "#5c330a", "#999999", "#66d9ff",
    "#e481a2", "#e996b1", "#e481a2", "#e06c92",
    "#e87da1", "#fff11c", "#ff6600"
]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(range(len(cmaplist)+1), len(cmaplist))
cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', cmaplist, len(cmaplist))

plt.matshow(example_data, fignum=False, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

I am not very good with matplotlib etc. so this may be a really obvious mistake. I am treating this just like its just a simple value lookup of the data but I am aware that that's not how it actually works but I can't think of a better approach with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to create a MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

example_data = np.array([list(range(20))]*4)
cmaplist = ["red", "limegreen", "blue", "gold"]*5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(0,len(cmaplist)+1)-0.5, len(cmaplist))
cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap',cmaplist, len(cmaplist))

im = ax.matshow(example_data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.show()
```

[image]

As can be seen, the color at positions 14 and 15 is the same, while position 15 should be yellow. This is present in matplotlib 2.1, in matplotlib 2.0.2 the issue seems not to be there. I therefore opened a [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9937) about it.

Solution:

The numbers you are mapping (which are integers here) are exactly on the edge of the boundaries. I'm not exactly sure what goes wrong here, but to be on the save side, you may use the middle between two integers as the boundary, i.e.

```
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(0,len(cmaplist)+1)-0.5, len(cmaplist))
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

example_data = np.array([list(range(20))]*4)
cmaplist = ["red", "limegreen", "blue", "gold"]*5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(0,len(cmaplist)+1)-0.5, len(cmaplist))
cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap',cmaplist, len(cmaplist))

im = ax.matshow(example_data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @BluBb_mADe Quick question: I did this with python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: regarding the MCVE. I wasn't sure if the number of colours or the way I specified the colours could've been responsible for this behaviour so I included everything. ps. python 2.7.14 matplotlib 2.1.0, numpy 1.13.3 all from pip on win10.

Comment: I created [an issue about this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9937), as this behaviour was not present in matplotlib 2.0.2 and in general you would of course expect a defined behaviour, even for bin edges.